# NSPopover OS X Application

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

I am developing a menu bar application for os x. I am using NSPopover to create a popup window.

However when some other application is full screen that popup is not visible. What settings should be set, so that popup window is always on top.

Answer (score 1):

I struggled with this as well. When I had this problem, I created a invisible window that would flow above all other windows, including full screen ones. The window would then activate the popover.

However, I found a much cleaner solution [here](https://www.raywenderlich.com/98178/os-x-tutorial-menus-popovers-menu-bar-apps).